# get Objects with with() clause RequestFactory GWT

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Hello I just set up RequestFactory for my GWT Project. It works nicely but I can't get the Object Fields of an Object
I have a BuslineProxy and a Bus Proxy

```
buslineContext.findAll().with("buses").fire(new Receiver<List<BuslineProxy>>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<BuslineProxy> response) {

        String requestedData="";
        for (BuslineProxy busline : response)
        {
            requestedData+="Busline " +busline.getName() +" with id " + busline.getId()+"\n";
            for(BusProxy bus : busline.getBuses())
            {
                requestedData+=bus.getId()+"\n";
            }
        }
        Window.alert(requestedData);
    }
});
```

My Server Object Busline has a List field called buses. I figured that I just simply need to put the field I want to access in the with clause. 
It doesn't work though and I only get all the buslines but their list of buses is empty. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Florent was correct that the data was empty due to a minor mistake.
The bigger problem though was that the entity proxy bus did not have a default constructor and a static findAll method, even though it is never instanciated directly. 
The constructor is empty and the findAll method returns null, but RequestFactory still needs them!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that Buses is not empty on the server when GWT is serializing the objects ?

You can check if you are correctly fetching Buses when you fetch your Busline, GWT will not do the database query itself if data isn't here (unless you are using some proxying mecanisms and an OpenSessionInViewFilter, or something similar).